How to dynamically retrieve and display the article type (e.g., "Jour.", "Conf.") in a LaTeX table?
I am trying to create a table that includes information about references from my bibliography file. My table has the following columns:
Row Number | Article Type | Citations | Author | Year | Title | Citation

Here is an example of one row in my table:
\stepcounter{rownumber}\arabic{rownumber} & Jour. &  18 & \citeauthor{pop02275} & \citeyear{pop02275} & \citetitle{pop02275} & \cite{pop02275} \\ \hline

I recently learned about the \citeauthor, \citeyear, and \citetitle commands, which help me avoid manually typing the author, year, and title for each entry. However, I'm still manually typing the article type ("Jour." for journal articles and "Conf." for conference papers).
My question is:
How can I dynamically retrieve and display the article type (e.g., Jour. for @article entries and Conf. for @inproceedings) in my LaTeX document? Ideally, I would like a command similar to \citetype that automatically prints the appropriate article type based on the entry in the bibliography file. I am using the ACM template in Overleaf.
\documentclass[acmsmall,natbib=false]{acmart}
% for using bibliography
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  datamodel=acmdatamodel,
  style=acmnumeric,
  sorting=ydnt
]{biblatex} 
% Reads bibliography entries 
\addbibresource{contents/bibliography.bib}

How can I achieve this dynamically without manually hardcoding the article type for each entry?
Here is a sample document:
\documentclass[acmsmall,screen]{acmart}

% Bibliography setup
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  datamodel=acmdatamodel,
  style=acmnumeric,
  sorting=ydnt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}


\newcommand{\articletype}[1]{
% complete me
}

\begin{document}

\title{Test Document for Article Type Extraction}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
In this document, we demonstrate how to dynamically extract article types from bibliography entries. 

For example, this paper \articletype{pop02275} is a journal article, while this one \articletype{pop02276} is a conference paper.

\printbibliography

\end{document}

And here is a sample bibliography file:
@article{pop02275,
  author = {John Doe},
  title = {Sample Journal Article},
  year = {2024},
  journal = {Sample Journal}
}

@inproceedings{pop02276,
  author = {Jane Smith},
  title = {Sample Conference Paper},
  year = {2024},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the Sample Conference}
}


Welcome to TeX.SE! As usual here please show us a short compilable TeX code you have so far, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Thanks. I have added a sample document.
